# Downtime (Computers and people)

Tags: meaning

I know I can say **I'm having downtime.**
How would you say it about a computer (system). **It has/ it's on downtime every night from 2 till 5?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  "**The system will undergo scheduled downtime every day from 2AM to 5AM.**" is just fine.  This is, of course, the opposite of *uptime*.  If it is unplanned downtime, usually *outage* or *network outage* is used instead.

Comment: I can't say **it will have.... or it will be on...** ?

Comment: Of course you can!  The former (*the system will have...*) sounds better.  I only wrote it the way I've seen it written in most announcements.

Comment: I was just trying to see if it **on** and **have** work

Answer (score 1):

*System downtime is from two to five every night* is short and sweet.

Answer (score 0):

I like the sound of this:

> The system will be experiencing downtime every night from 2 to 5 for [maintenance, repair, etc.].

Comment: Please use block quotes (>) for quotations and examples, not verbatim blocks.

Comment: What is the "some" menat to imply? That it won't always be down for the whole period? Otherwise, omot "some".